# flutter User.Read azure active directory "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Tags: flutter, azure, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I am trying to get the data of a signed in user using Microsoft graph API. I work with the "aad_oauth" package in flutter. When signing in, an access token is provided. This access token is then used in a http.get request.

However every time I try to get the data, the following error appears.
"{"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation:"

I also added a permission at the ad admin center.
[image]

That's how I get the access token
[image]

This is my http request
[image]

Comment: The api url should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

Comment: @TinyWang I have already tried this url, although it didn't work.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created an Azure AD application and added **`user.read`** permission:

[image]

Now I generated access token via Postman with below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code



client_id:1b323717-80d8-4172-b141-XXXXXX
client_secret:GTT8Q~PErY3nTbj9LO8Nkkm2ai.XXXXXXX
scope:user.read
code:code
redirect_uri: redirect_uri
```

[image]

To get the details of the signed-in user, I ran the below query by including bearer token:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your Answer.
How did you get the ''code" param at your get request?

Comment: I just deleted my app on the emulator and recompiled it. Surprisingly, it works now ^^.
Thanks anyway!